# java.lang.ClassCastException: fi.rogerstudio.possis.MainApplication cannot be cast to com.facebook.react.ReactApplication

Tags: reactjs, push-notification, react-native, android-push-notification

I am getting this error when receiving push notification only when the app is open, foreground mode!

Does anyone had this issue before using the Firebase push notification and react-native-fcm?

COde:

```
      showLocalNotification(notif) {
        FCM.presentLocalNotification({
            title: notif.title,
            body: notif.body,
            priority: "high",
            click_action: notif.click_action,
            show_in_foreground: true,
            local: true
        });
    }

Mainapplication.java:


public class MainApplication extends MultiDexApplication {

  // Needed for `react-native link`
  public List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
    return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
        // Add your own packages here!
        // TODO: add cool native modules
//            new MainReactPackage(),

            new RNBackgroundGeolocation(),
            // Needed for `react-native link`

            new FIRMessagingPackage(),
            //new RNBackgroundGeolocation(),
            //new RNFirebasePackage(),
            new VectorIconsPackage()
            //new RNFirebaseMessagingPackage()
    );
  }
}
```

Full Error I am getting:

java.lang.ClassCastException: fi.rogerstudio.possis.MainApplication cannot be cast to com.facebook.react.ReactApplication
                      at com.evollu.react.fcm.MessagingService$1.run(MessagingService.java:41)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)

Answer (score 0):

For someone who may be coming to this 3.5 years after the fact, the solution is to make sure your main application extends ReactApplication,

```
public class MainApplication extends MultiDexApplication, ReactApplication
```

and then implement `getReactNativeHost` like this:

```
public class MainApplication extends MultiDexApplication {
  ...
  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost =
      new ReactNativeHost(this) {
        @Override
        public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
          return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
        }

        @Override
        protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
          @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
          List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
          // Packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here, for example:
          // packages.add(new MyReactNativePackage());
          return packages;
        }

        @Override
        protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
          return "index";
        }
      };

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return mReactNativeHost;
  }
 ...
}
```